# Sufficient Condition for an Affine Map

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

Let $f$ be a map on an affine space $A$ (i.e. any map taking points to points, not necessarily an affine map). Suppose that for any two pairs of points $(p_1,q_1)$ and $(p_2,q_2)$ in $A$ with $\overrightarrow{p_1q_1} = \overrightarrow{p_2q_2}$ we have $\overrightarrow{f(p_1)f(q_1)} = \overrightarrow{f(p_2)f(q_2)}$. Then $f$ induces a well defined map on the vector space associated with $A$, call it $f'$, via $f'(\overrightarrow{pq}) = \overrightarrow{f(p)f(q)}$. Is $f'$ necessarily linear, or in other words, is $f$ necessarily an affine map? If so, how can one prove this? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: What does $p_1 q_1 = p_2 q_2$ mean?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Where I wrote $p_1q_1$, I meant the vector from $p_1$ to $q_1$, and similarly for the other cases. I've changed the notation in the post to make this clearer.

Comment: @reuns It means the vector going from $f(p)$ to $f(q)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By picking an origin we can think of $A$ as a vector space $V$ WLOG, and then by replacing $f$ with $f - f(0)$ (which preserves the desired condition) we can assume that $f(0) = 0$ WLOG. Then the condition is that if $p_1 - q_1 = p_2 - q_2$ then $f(p_1) - f(q_1) = f(p_2) - f(q_2)$. Rearranging and setting $q_2 = 0$, the condition is that

$$f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$$

(where $a = p_2, b = q_1, a + b = p_1$). In other words, $f$ is additive; this condition is necessary and sufficient, since if $f$ is additive then $f(p_i) - f(q_i) = f(p_i - q_i)$.

So the question is equivalent to asking whether an additive function $f : V \to V$ is linear. This is false over every field except the prime vector spaces $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{F}_p$, since every other field $F$ is a vector space of dimension $\ge 2$ over its prime subfield and hence admits nontrivial additive maps $F \to F$ which are not $F$-linear.

When $F = V = \mathbb{R}$ the equation $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$ is called [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) and nonlinear solutions to it (which are necessarily everywhere non-measurable) can be "constructed" using the axiom of choice to find a (Hamel) basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  However, in this case $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear as soon as one imposes any of a number of very mild additional hypotheses, e.g. $f$ is continuous at any point, measurable at any point, bounded on any interval...

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks!